# What am I missing in this simple Bash script?

Tags: bash, shell

```
#!/bin/bash
#Toggle Script

# $dirserver/A  -> $dirproject/{trunk|branches}/A

if [[ "$1" == "dw" || -z "$1" ]]; then
        echo "[+] Delete old link ( $dirserver/A )... "
        rm "$dirserver/A"
    if [[ "$(readlink -f $dirserver/A)" == *"branches"* ]]; then
                ln -s "$dirproject/trunk/A" "$dirserver/A"
                echo "[+] Done. You are now in TRUNK"
    else
                ln -s "$dirproject/branches/A" "$dirserver/A"
                echo "[+] Done. You are now in BRANCH."

    fi
fi
```

Expected functionality: Do toggle between symlinks, BRANCH or TRUNK .

Error: `./toggle.sh dw` Always end in BRANCH.

Notes: No. There is no word "branches" when it points to trunk.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Look closely at `rm "$dirserver/A";  if [[ "$(readlink -f $dirserver/A)"`

Comment: Answers do not belong in questions. Use the "add an answer" button to add your own answer, don't edit it into the question. If someone else already added an answer that includes your solution, just click the checkmark next to it to mark your problem solved.

Comment: FYI, you can simplify the first check to `if [[ ${1:-dw} = "dw" ]]; then`.

Answer (score 0):

You are deleting the old link before checking it. Just do not delete it at all, only overwrite.

```
if [[ "$1" == "dw" || -z "$1" ]]; then
    if [[ "$(readlink -f "$dirserver/A")" == *branches* ]]; then
       ln -f -s "$dirproject/trunk/A" "$dirserver/A"
    else
       ln -f -s "$dirproject/branches/A" "$dirserver/A"
    fi
fi
```